# How do I dismiss preview UI controller in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I dont understand why its not dismissing. Im using replaykit in my app and Im trying to dismiss the UI that pops up after its done recording the screen. There is a cancel button on the top left side and when I press it the preview controller doesn't dismiss. There is a delegate function to dismiss the controller but its not working for me. I feel this is an easy fix but Im not sure what Im doing wrong. Please help me. If you need more info let me know. Thank you!

```
 func startRecoding() {


if RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder().available {
    RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder().startRecordingWithMicrophoneEnabled(true, handler: { (error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil { // Recording has started

        } else {
            // Handle error
        }
    })
} else {
    // Display UI for recording being unavailable

}


}

 func stopRecording() {

RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder().stopRecordingWithHandler { (previewController: RPPreviewViewController?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if previewController != nil {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Recording", message: "Do you wish to discard or view your gameplay recording?", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let discardAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Discard", style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in
            RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder().discardRecordingWithHandler({ () -> Void in
                // Executed once recording has successfully been discarded
            })
        }

        let viewAction = UIAlertAction(title: "View", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(previewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)



        })

        alertController.addAction(discardAction)
        alertController.addAction(viewAction)

        self.view?.window?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        // Handle error
    }
  }



  }


func previewControllerDidFinish(previewController: RPPreviewViewController) {
    previewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Please show the code that you are using to display the view that you are now trying to dismiss.

Comment: okay I will update the op.

Comment: I updated the code you can check it out now.

Comment: What are you doing to set the view controller's delegate?

Comment: Is previewControllerDidFinish getting called?

Comment: No I just checked.

Comment: @JeffWolski I didn't set the view controllers delegate. Could that be the problem?

Comment: That could definitely be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you set the delegate for your preview view controller.

```
RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder().stopRecordingWithHandler { (previewController: RPPreviewViewController?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if previewController != nil {

        //  Try adding this line
        previewController.delegate = self
        //

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Recording", message: "Do you wish to discard or view your gameplay recording?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: Okay then what do I put inside my previewControllerDidFinish?

Comment: You can do that.  Or you can dismiss using a method that gets triggered by a button.